# An Upcoming Situation

Tags: germany, residency, blue-card

At the moment I have a German Blue Card after finishing my Msc in Germany, valid till the expiry date of my Passport (05.2021), the problem is that after the expiry of my passport I will not be able to renew it before my 30s birthday in 09.2021 cuz the embassy will not renew it for me before I reach 30 and get the final exemption from the military service. Meaning that there will be a gap of approx 4 months for me without a national passport. What can I do in these 4 months to be able to live and work legally in Germany? Will the Auslanderbehorde just give me a notification of deportation or they will cooperate and maybe issue me something temporary till I sort out my a new passport?

I do not care about my ability to travel in these months but I just want to keep my job and live and work legally. 
Any help or maybe guidance for what can be done?

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: @MJeffryes why would it matter?

Comment: @MJeffryes: What does my nationality have to do with the situation? All non-EU citizens should be treated equally.

Comment: Not at all. Germany and the EU have treaties with lots of non-EU states which give their citizens extra rights – and vice versa. If you are a citizen of such a country, things can be much simpler. For example citizens of Switzerland, Liechtenstein and Norway are almost treated alike EU citizens, and citzens of the USA, Canada, Japan, Australia and New Zealand have some benefits.

Comment: @phoog It seems to me that one possible solution to the problem would be persuading the passport issuing country to renew it.

Comment: @MJeffryes: I am trying to find any way to do so and will keep trying. But the question is what if I cannot renew it, especially that two months after the expiry date I would be eligible for applying for German citizenship as I would be living here for 6 years. That's why I am asking whether it might be considered by the ABH that I am living there and studying and working there so maybe they will try to help with any paper that allows me to work and live in these few months until I sort the Passport issue out.

Comment: There are valid reasons one cannot renew the passport. Failure to do so doesn't result in deportation, but you may be fined (even years later). Talk to your local *Ausländerbehörde* and explain the problem. They will tell you what they are up to do.