# Does a speeding ticket or a false parking affect Niederlassungserlaubnis application?

Tags: germany

Does a single speeding ticket (Drove 38 kmh in a 30 zone) and a parking fine affect NE application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Driving 8km/h too fast in town is only a *Ordnungswidrigkeit* (misbehaviour), wrong parking, too.

They don't affect the *Niederlassungserlaubnis* application.

It is affected as soon a *Verkehrsstraftat* ("traffic crime") is involved. Some things which may be considered a *Verkehrsstraftat* by a judge are for example driving without license, driving while on drugs, hit&run, and failure to render assistance. Driving way too fast, or driving slightly too fast and causing a crash, or driving carelessly and causing a crash can also be considered a *Verkehrsstraftat*.

Comment: I was asking that because I don't have much of time cuz I will be faced with that situation  https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/15231/an-upcoming-situation?noredirect=1#comment26288_15231  And I would appriciate if u can provide me with any help.

Comment: Your statement "It is affected as soon as *crime* is involved" is not helpful.  In legal terms, in England and Wales at least, a speeding ticket *is* a crime.  (Parking ticket is much less likely to be.)  You would be *much* better using the German word.  (Which I would translate as "serious crime", or possibly "felony" - but that probably has too much baggage.)

Comment: We aren't talking about England and Wales, and I gave examples what is considered a crime in traffic – Verkehrsstraftat – in Germany for that very reason.

Comment: @Janka - but you used the word *crime*.  That is an English word, and in English it covers things like "speeding tickets" ... which is why the German word would be much better.

Comment: @MartinBonner whether "crime" includes "speeding tickets" (or, more precisely, whether it includes "speeding") depends on the jurisdiction, not the language.  The real reason it's better to use the German word is to avoid ambiguity that could be introduced by different possible translations of the same word.

Comment: @phoog Can you point to an English-speaking jurisdiction where speeding is *not* a crime?

Comment: @MartinBonner [about half of US states](https://www.nhtsa.gov/staticfiles/nti/pdf/811457.pdf).